# What are canon feats showing Blue Marvel's maximum strength, speed and energy output?

Tags: marvel, blue-marvel

Adam Brashear has been shown to be able to keep physical pace with some of the strongest beings in Marvel, including the likes of Hulk and Sentry.

I was wondering if there were any canon scans or sources showing him going all out and thus giving an idea of his upper limits of strength, speed, and energy output?